# Idea to speed up array processing

Tags: python, performance, numpy, parallel-processing, database-performance

I want to create a dataset *B* by processing a dataset *A*. Therefore, every column in A (~ 2 Mio.) has to be processed in a batch-fashion (putting through a neural network), resulting in 3 outputs which are stacked together and then e.g. stored in a numpy array.

My code looks like the following, which seems to be not the best solution.

```
# Load data
data = get_data()

# Storage for B
B = np.empty(shape=data.shape)

# Process data
for idx, data_B in enumerate(data):
    # Process data
    a, b, c = model(data_B)

    # Reshape and feed in B
    B[idx * batch_size:batch_size * (idx + 1)] = np.squeeze(np.concatenate((a, b, c), axis=1))
```

I am looking for ideas to speed up the stacking or assigning process. I do not know if it is possible for parallel processing since everything should be stored in the same array finally (the ordering is not important). Is there any python framework I can use?

Loading the data takes 29s (only done once), stacking and assigning takes 20s for a batch size of only 2. The *model* command takes < 1s, allocating the array takes 5s and all other part <1s.

Comment: My guess is that processing the data (the `model` call) takes longer than the iteration mechanism, including stacking.  You could,of course, test that with a comparison run that does minimal processing.

Comment: I know [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) framework is focused on dataset processing, and allows you to transform datasets efficiently (uses numpy arrays under the hood). You could give it a try.

Comment: No that is not the case. Please see my additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays shapes, and especially number of dimensions, is unclear.  I can make a few guesses from what works in the code.  Your times suggest that things are very large, so memory management may a big issue. Creating large temporary arrays takes time.

What is `data.shape`?  Probably 2d at least; `B` has the same shape

```
B = np.empty(shape=data.shape)
```

Now you iterate on the 1st dimension of `data`; lets call them rows, though they might be 2d or larger:

```
# Process data
for idx, data_B in enumerate(data):
    # Process data
    a, b, c = model(data_B)
```

What the nature of `a`, etc.  I'm assuming arrays, with a shape similar to `data_B`.  But that just a guess.

```
    # Reshape and feed in B
    B[idx * batch_size:batch_size * (idx + 1)] =
         np.squeeze(np.concatenate((a, b, c), axis=1)
```

For `concatenate` to work `a,b,c` must be 2d (at least).  Lets guess they are all (n,m).  The result is (n,3m).  Why the squeeze?  Is the shape (1,3m)?

I don't know `batch_size`.  But with anything other than 1 I don't think this works.  `B[idx:idx+1, :] = ...` works since `idx` ranges the `B.shape[0]`, but with other values it would produce an error.

With this batchsize slice indexing it almost looks like you are trying to string out the iteration values in a long 1d array, `batchsize` values per iteration.  But that doesn't fit with `B` matching `data` in shape.

That puzzle aside, I wonder if you really need the concatenate.  Can you initial `B` so you can assign values directly, e.g.

```
B[idx, 0, ...] = a
B[idx, 1, ...] = b
etc
```

Reshaping a array after filling is trivial.  Even transposing axes isn't too time consuming.

Comment: Thanks, your last suggestion gave me a speedup of ~30%!